# Why Mysql is not handling case sensitive cases

Tags: mysql, cas

When I test below sql queries:

```
    1.  SELECT * FROM  table WHERE  username='username' AND password = 'password';

    2.  SELECT * FROM  table WHERE  username='Username' AND password = 'Password';
```

Both queries are returning the same result even though username and password are case sensitive

Comment: You should not store passwords plaintext though.

Answer (score 3):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE  username='Username' AND binary password = 'Password';
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for **Case Sensitive** query

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `column` = 'value'
```

In your case it will become:

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE BINARY username='Username' AND BINARY password = 'Password';
```